# Spark to JDBC: Py4JJavaError - Connection initiated but no exactly one provider

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, driver

I am resolving an error received writing a data frame in PySpark via JDBC connection with Kerberos authentication using keytab and principal in database properties argument.

The connection is initiated via JDBC successfully with Kerberos credentials as I do not receive the telling GSS initiate failed error but I get:

```
Illegal Argument Exception: requirement failed: JDBC connection     initiated but not exactly one provider found which can handle it. Found        active providers:
```

The code I ran was:

```
df_spark.write.jdbc(url=db_props[‘url’], table=‘schema.table’,   mode=‘overwrite’, properties=db_props)
```

Upon closer inspection, the Illegal Argument Exception is a Py4JJavaError sourced from the java_gateway.py module in py4j. I can’t find any more info on the error. Thanks for your help if anyone has seen it or can discern what is taking place!

Comment: What are these _"active providers"_?? Maybe you have **several** JDBC drivers in your CLASSPATH, or something.

Answer (score 0):

this is a general question, so this is a general answer:

- good, but old article: https://datamountaineer.com/2016/01/15/spark-jdbc-sql-server-kerberos/
- for Spark 3.1 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html
- or even a pull request about Kerberos in JDBC: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24421

Please, try to learn something, try something and then ask more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to initiate GSS by adding keytab and principal to db properties argument for .write.JDBC. However, I now get an IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: JDBC connection initiated but not exactly one connection provider found. Found providers:”

Comment: nice! you might add these lines to your original question with code and errors. It will create a nice question suitable for stackoverflow. Hopefully somebody will be able to answer